# Thread.CurrentPrincipal List on POST requests, but not GET requests

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, c#-4.0, httpcontext

I have a RESTful WCF application that is hosted in a WebProject. I am using a HttpModule to authenticate a header on incoming requests, and if the header and URL are valid, I set both

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = myCustomPrincipal;
```

This works perfectly for GET requests, but when I do a POST, and check the Thread.CurrentPrincipal, it is set to an instance of the WindowsPrincipal class. I have read on a few blog posts that both the HttpContext.Current.User AND the Thread.CurrentPrincipal should both be set to the same IPrincipal object, but when I assign

```
HttpContext.Current.User = myCurrentPrincipal;
```

my service is never getting hit, and a 401 UnAuthorized message is being sent back that I never actually assigned.

*note* I am assigning these principals in my context_PostAuthorizeRequest method that I have attached to the context's like named handler.

Please help. What am I doing wrong? below is an example of my webconfig's httpModules configuration:

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="PublicServiceSecurity" type="Company.PublicService.PublicServiceSecurity,PublicService" />
  <add name="ErrorModule" type="Company.Web.ErrorModule,WebComponentLibrary" />
  <add name="HbnSessionModule" type="Company.Web.HbnSessionModule,WebComponentLibrary" />
</httpModules>
```

Comment: note: as soon as I remove the HttpContext.Current.User assignment, my WCF service is hit as expected (well almost, still getting the WindowsPrincipal rather than myCustomPrincipal).

Comment: For now I have moved my assignment of the HttpContext.User into the actual WCF service, and I am no longer using an HttpModule, but I find it very strange that the Principal for the HttpContext.User is lost between the module, and my WCF service.

Comment: It behaves so. Use WCF context instead. What technology for REST you are using?

Comment: @Regfor, I am not sure what you are asking. I am hosting my WCF's as svc's in an asp.net website, so I have the ability to use httpmodules for all of my requests. I can't use the WCF context in the httpmodule because it's before the WCF structure has been created right?